# How do I style a circular vertically-loading progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a very unique progress bar that visually looks like a glass orb filling up with liquid. Unfortunately, because of the rounded shape, the traditional method of modifying the height doesn't work so well (as demonstrated with this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/usuwvaq5/2/).

As you can see, having the div height "slide up" is not the desired visual. I have also tried playing a bit with css `clip`, but was unable to get it to work for me. How can I create the visual effect of the glass "filling" with the second image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `background-position:bottom;` to `#inner-progress`:

```
#inner-progress {
  background-image: url(https://www.novilar.com/img/battle/ui/purification_meter_bar.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position:bottom;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0%;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9aLLkete/)

Comment: Simple solution for a simple problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem :D Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Gray probably has the best answer, but here's an alternative:

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ptcfth5h/)

This approach uses **css** for the animation, instead of **javascript**. JS is only used here to trigger the animation, the rest is css.

This uses the css `transition` property to "animate" the height as it changes from 100% to 0%. The only notable change in the html is that I swapped the background of the `inner` with the `outer`.

Perhaps this answer will be a better solution to a future reader of this thread - depending on their implementation and/or preferences.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inner-progress').addClass("load");
});
```

```css
#outer-progress {
    background-image: url(https://www.novilar.com/img/battle/ui/purification_meter_bar.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#inner-progress {
  background-image: url(https://www.novilar.com/img/battle/ui/purification_meter_background.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
    transition: height 3s;
  -webkit-transition: height 3s;
}

.progress-value {
  color: #FFF !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
}

.load{
  height: 0% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer-progress">
  <div id="inner-progress" value="0" max="100"></div>
  <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
</div>
```